I am having some problems with Python's subprocess module
I am trying to do something with the Tidal API and I wanted to execute this command using subprocess:
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://openapi.tidal.com/search?query=The%20Weekend%20Anti%20Up&offset=0&limit=10&countryCode=US&popularity=WORLDWIDE' \
  -H 'accept: application/vnd.tidal.v1+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <here is my access code and it is a few lines long> \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.tidal.v1+json'

In python, I tried to use this code:
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["curl", "-X", "'GET'", "\\", "'https://openapi.tidal.com/search?query=The%20Weekend%20Anti%20Up&offset=0&limit=10&countryCode=US&popularity=WORLDWIDE'", "\\", "-H", "'accept: application/vnd.tidal.v1+json'", "\\", "-H", "'Authorization: Bearer <here is my acces code again>'", "\\", "-H", "'Content-Type: application/vnd.tidal.v1+json'"])

When I run the command in my terminal, it works, but when I do it with subprocess, I get this output:
curl: (3) URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function
curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
curl: (3) URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function
curl: (3) URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function
curl: (3) URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function

Hopefully someone can help!

For one thing, you don't need the extra quotes around "'GET'", and you don't need the extra backslashes "\\".

I need to use \ because "" is an escape character

The backslashes in the curl command are only for shell line continuation.  They aren't literally passed to curl.

How do I write only one, because when I put only one, it is escaping my " and then it doesn't work

You don't need them at all.  Their only purpose was to allow the curl command to be written on several lines, to be easier to read.  Your code does not need that at all.  Get rid of them.

You are using control structures that are used by a terminal to specify where parameters start and end, but that is not necessary in a subprocess, since there you specify the parameters as a list of strings.
You do this in two ways: with "\\", this is used by a terminal to specify that the command is not finished, and that the terminal should read the next line and essentially "concatenate" the two lines, but here there are no new lines.
A second problem is the use of quotes, in a terminal, one writes foo 'bar qux' to specify that bar qux is one parameter with a space as content of the parameter. But the quotes are then removed by the shell.
You thus can use:
import subprocess

subprocess.run(
    [
        'curl',
        '-X',
        'GET',
        'https://openapi.tidal.com/search?query=The%20Weekend%20Anti%20Up&offset=0&limit=10&countryCode=US&popularity=WORLDWIDE',
        '-H',
        'accept: application/vnd.tidal.v1+json',
        '-H',
        'Authorization: Bearer <here is my acces code again>',
        '-H',
        'Content-Type: application/vnd.tidal.v1+json',
    ]
)
As for the querystring, I would advise to use a tool to convert a dictionary into a querystring: querystrings are rather complicated with percentage encoding, and it is easy to make mistakes.
